# Ajax PDO Select id IN

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have strange problem, I use PDO in Ajax request:

```
$sql= "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE id_educator IN ('$educator_extra')";
$data = $handler->prepare($sql);
$data->execute();
$result4 = $data->fetchAll();
echo $result4;
```

and this return

```
string(59) "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE id_educator IN ('31,29,25')" array(0) { }
```

but if i change $sql

```
$sql= "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE id_educator IN (31,29,25)";
$data = $handler->prepare($sql);
$data->execute();
$result4 = $data->fetchAll();
```

this return

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["user_id"]=> string(2) "30" [0]=> string(2) "30" } }
```

if I remove commands form $educator_extra my ajax request dont work someone know what I should do ?

Comment: Try this `$sql= "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE id_educator IN ($educator_extra)";` note i remove '.
In your sql example "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE id_educator IN ('31,29,25')" it's exaclty same to :  "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE id_educator = '31,29,25'"

Comment: Not really much point preparing a query with no parameters in it